# Next.js: Caching of fetch() response in route handlers

Tags: next.js

I am reading the Next.js documentation and it says:

> In Route handlers, fetch requests are not memoized as Route Handlers
> are not part of the React component tree.

Does this mean that the response of `fetch()` is not cached when it's called inside route handlers?

I am confused because there is another sentence saying:

> `fetch` requests that use the `POST` method are also automatically cached.
> Unless it's inside a Route Handler that uses the `POST` method, then it
> will not be cached.

The second sentence sounds like the response of `fetch()` is cached if it's called inside the `GET` route handler.

So - is `fetch()` cached or not inside `GET` route handler?

Comment: It looks like the first sentence is about the `fetch()` extended by React, and the second sentence is about the `fetch()` extended by Next.js, but I am still confused.

Comment: To the best of my understanding, the first sentence is saying that the result is not cached on the client-side React cache, while second sentence says that the result is cached on the server-side Data cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#data-cache,

If you look at the graphics, there is two layers of cache, one on React's rendering side, which is the in-memory cache, and another is on Next.js side which is the Data Cache that's persistent. Route handlers will not store it in-memory because there's no React to control the in-memory cache in that environment, but it will store it in the Data Cache, which is controlled by Nextjs.